# How to set a flag when cookies are disabled

Tags: session, cookies

I'm writing a mobile website and have a splash screen display briefly before the site loads.

I am using the following code in my index.php file to redirect to the splash screen

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['splash'])){
    $_SESSION['splash']=true;
    header('Location: splash.html');
}

//Do normal index.php
```

The splash screen redirects back to index.php after 1 second which this time skips the splash screen section and loads the site normally.
This all works really well until someone disables cookies!
In this case, the session variable 'splash' never gets set so you just get an endless loop displaying the splash screen again and again and again....

What's the best way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make PHP pass the session ID as GET variable instead of storing it in a cookie. [See here](http://my.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) for info on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So if I've got this right, I just need to change my if statement to `if(!isset($_SESSION['splash']) && !SID){`. Is that the way it works? The session variable can be set if cookies are enabled, otherwise SID will be set?

Comment: No, you must append SID to all your links, so if cookies are off it adds a strink like phpsessid=000000000 (the value that couldn't be stored in the cookie), if cookies are enabled it is empty. In your case, simply append SID to the Location header.